# Azure PHP Enabling Diagnostics

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-powershell

I had many difficulties understanding and enabling diagnostic module in Windows Azure to grab performance data + plus all the facilities offered by the module. As I lost my way many times with various post on the internet I thought to post a clear guide to express the way I did it..

Step 1 : Install Windows Azure PowerShell tool according to the instructions from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/21/creating-a-php-web-role-in-windows-azure.aspx)

Step 2 : Run Windows Azure PowerShell as Administrator.

Step 3 : Get the current Azure publish settings

```
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

Step 4 : Save the file in a knows folder and remove any spaces in the name. (ex.  .publishsettings )

Step 5 : import the publish settings file downloaded above.

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile <path_to_downloaded>\<publishsettings_file_name>
```

Step 6 : Create Windows Azure Project. (this will create a folder with many configeration files)

```
New-AzureServiceProject <myAzureProject>
```

Step 6 : Add Windows Azure Role

```
Add-AzurePHPWebRole <myWebRole>
```

Step 6 : go to the project folder and Edit ServiceDefinition.csdef and import diagnostic module to it .

```
  <WebRole name="myWebRole" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
  ..
```

Step 7 : Edit ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg,ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and ServiceConfiguration.cscfg(make a copy of the ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and rename it for this file if does not exist) and storage connection string to all the three files.

```
  <Role name="myWebRole">
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"       value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage_name>;AccountKey=<storage_key>" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    ..
```

Step 6 : Add a diagnostics.wadcfg file to the folder in the azure project folder. It can be as following to be start with but need to be changed to your exact specifications to collect diagnostic information.

```
<DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration" configurationChangePollInterval="PT1M" overallQuotaInMB="4096">
   <DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs bufferQuotaInMB="10"
      scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Error"
      scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" />

   <Logs bufferQuotaInMB="0"
      scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose"
      scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M" />

   <Directories bufferQuotaInMB="0" 
      scheduledTransferPeriod="PT5M">

      <!-- These three elements specify the special directories 
           that are set up for the log types -->
      <CrashDumps container="wad-crash-dumps" directoryQuotaInMB="256" />
      <FailedRequestLogs container="wad-frq" directoryQuotaInMB="256" />
      <IISLogs container="wad-iis" directoryQuotaInMB="256" />
   </Directories>

   <PerformanceCounters bufferQuotaInMB="0" scheduledTransferPeriod="PT1M">
      <!-- The counter specifier is in the same format as the imperative 
           diagnostics configuration API -->
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration 
         counterSpecifier="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" sampleRate="PT5M" />
      <PerformanceCounterConfiguration 
         counterSpecifier="\Memory\Available Mbytes" sampleRate="PT5M" />
   </PerformanceCounters>
   <WindowsEventLog bufferQuotaInMB="0"
      scheduledTransferLogLevelFilter="Verbose"
      scheduledTransferPeriod="PT5M">
      <!-- The event log name is in the same format as the imperative 
           diagnostics configuration API -->
      <DataSource name="System!*" />
   </WindowsEventLog>
</DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration>
```

Step 6 : Now configuration changes were added and need to publish the new settings to the Windows Azure cloud by.

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject
```

or

```
Publish-AzureServiceProject –ServiceName <myNewServiceName>
```

This process will take some time and end of it you have diagnostics enabled Windows Azure service ..

Important Note : This is a brief guide to basic diagnostic setup for more customization can refer various Microsoft Silver lining blog posts such as [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/21/creating-a-php-web-role-in-windows-azure.aspx)

Comment: Is this a tutorial or a question? I like the step by step nature of your post. But can't find something to answer.